# Referencing XML results using Python Requests Library

Tags: python, json, xml, api, python-requests

I am using Requests library in Python to work with a company's API.

However the results are in XML format.

How do I reference the data that I want in Python or using requests? Is there away to convert this data to JSON?

Here is an example:

XML:

```
    <result xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Starbucks.Location.WebAPI.Models">
<paging>
   <total>21933</total>
   <offset>0</offset>
   <limit>10</limit>
   <returned>10</returned>
</paging>
<stores>
   <store>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>Store1</name>
      <brandName>BrandName</brandName>
      <storeNumber>34601-20281</storeNumber>
   </store>
   <store>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>Store2</name>
      <brandName>BrandName</brandName>
      <storeNumber>20281</storeNumber>
   </store>
```

My Python code looks a little something like this:

```
for i in range(0, 1):
   myParameters = {'limit': '50', 'offset': i*50}
   response = requests.get(url, params=myParameters)

   print response #Here is where I want to print the data in json format
```

In that example response returns xml format.

I would like to create a csv or text file or something using specific attributes of each store. For instance grab the store id and place it in a column in a csv file.

But I don't know how to reference the id tag in the xml result. I figured converting the data to json would help but when I use Requests .json() or json library I get the error: `No JSON object could be decoded`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many XML parsers, however- as you are interested in getting JSON you might want to try `xmltodict` with `json`, which can get you there in one line.

```
json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(response))
```

Comment: Thanks! So it returns a json object but when I try to get info I get an error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

The code I use is `newResponse['result']['stores'][1]['name']`

Comment: Seems you have a Json array instead of dict in of the result, store or name- try to traverse one layer at a time until you figure out the mix up

Comment: Then try newResponse[1]

Comment: Same error, however I removed json.dumps() and now I get results up until `newResponse['result']['stores'].`..`newResponse['result']['stores'][1]` returns a different error: `KeyError: 1`

Comment: UPDATE: So, I took out `json.dumps()` and wrote `newResponse['result']['stores']['store'][1]['name']' and that seemed to work!

Comment: Try this `json.dumps(xmltodict.parse("<xml>"+response+"</xml>"))` then  `newResponse['xml'][1]['result']['stores']['store'][1]['name']` . I've actually had this problem before- its due to the fact that your xml does not have a 'root' tag, and is thus not quite valid xml.

Comment: Error: `cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Response' objects`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90069/discussion-between-john-and-auto).